# how to generate same barcode for same product and if the product is different it should create a new barcode

Tags: java, html, jsp

[image]

how to generate same  barcode for same product and if the product is different it should create a new barcode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barcode code usualy generated by using product code .Because the product code is unique (differenct product cannot have a same barcode value).

Lets say for Product1 code is PR00001
and for      Product2 code is PR00002

Select the the Product which you want to generated the barcode ,Use the Product code to generated the barcode. By the way, when ever you are generating barcode must be same for sames product.

Comment: yes barcode should be same for same product

Answer (score -1):

I think you could implement it by store the product_id and the reference of the barcode in Redis or some cache system, anytime if the id matches, fetch the code by reference in the cache directly.Otherwise, generate it and store the id and reference in the cache for the later use.